# Find row in 2 columns where IF AND is meet between these 2 cells in respective row

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need a function that will check if column C has a cell with "2/1/2020" date and also column D has a cell with a specific word, let's say "Savinjska" (in my case) in the same row. And return the rows where these combinations in both columns are meet.
Further, these found rows are needed to collect 2 numbers from the E and F column and divide them (F/E).

I hope it is clear. I don't have much experience with Match, Index or Row functions...
You can check my spreadsheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N_quzKffRB5iDT1b2qZ0VCEycq5vYJ7uY48HXz5n6P4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in row 2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((C2:C=DATE(2020, 2, 1))*(D2:D="Savinjska"), F2:F/E2:E, ))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 1):

Enter the formula in a cell in row 2:
`=if(and(C2=DATE(2020,2,1),D2="Savinjska"),F2/E2,"")`

---

- `and`: this enables two logical expressions to be evaluated
- `C2=DATE(2020,2,1)`: this compares the date in Cell C2 to the desired date
- `D2="Savinjska"`: Compares the value in cell D2 to the desired name
- if the formularmula evaluates as TRUE, the it returns `F2/E2`

Comment: There is always something new to be learned (learnt, spelling??. That is why, IMO at least, the answer by @player0 is a better solution. It has the particular advantage of employing `ARRAYFORMULA` (so that as additional data rows are added, the formula will automatically execute). This is possible by the clever evaluation of the date and the text. Instead of using the conventional `AND`, the two logical conditions are multiplied: true x true = true; true x false = false.